# Creating custom language minted

Tags: minted

I would like to create some sort of pseudocode language to write algorithms in `minted`. I have a set of keywords I'd like highlighted, but I don't know how to create something that makes `minted` accept these keywords, and create a language.

What can I do and are there any resources that I can take a look at to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a new lexer and/or formatter for pygmentize in python, see

https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/#custom-lexers-and-formatters